# Problem with Auto_Increment in MySQL and PDO in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am performing an `INSERT` with PDO in PHP into a table in a MySQL database and when the `INSERT` fails with "`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry ... for key...`" the index for the column with Auto_Increment enabled still advances.  For example I get ID equals 10, 11, 13, 15, 17.  The insert attempts at id 12, 14 and 16 failed with the `SQLSTATE[23000]` error.  If the INSERT fails shouldn't the Auto_Increment not advance?  Am I missing something in my code?  Is this an issue I should care about?

My environment is;

O/S: MS Windows 10

Web Server: Apache 2.4x

PHP: v.7.3.9

MYSQL: v.8.0.17 MySQL Community Server

Postman: v.7.24.0

My code is as follows;

Postman:

Request Type: `Post`

Request: `http://www.closingdocs3.tst/api/state/create_many.php`
Body:

```
{
  "data": [
    {"abbreviation": "AK", "fullName": "Alaska",                         "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "AL", "fullName": "Alabama",                        "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "AR", "fullName": "Arkansas",                       "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "AS", "fullName": "American Samoa ",                "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "AZ", "fullName": "Arizona",                        "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "CA", "fullName": "California",                     "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "CO", "fullName": "Colorado",                       "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "CT", "fullName": "Connecticut",                    "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "DC", "fullName": "District of Columbia",           "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "DE", "fullName": "Delaware",                       "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"": ""},
    {"": "", "": ""},
    {"": "", "": "", "": ""},
    {"abbreviation": "", "": "", "": ""},
    {"abbreviation": "X1", "": "", "": ""},
    {"abbreviation": "X1", "fullName": "", "": ""},
    {"abbreviation": "X1", "fullName": "X-Ray One State", "": ""},
    {"abbreviation": "X1", "fullName": "X-Ray One State", "createdBy": ""},
    {"abbreviation": "X1", "fullName": "X-Ray One State", "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "X1", "fullName": "X-Ray One State", "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "X2", "fullName": "X-Ray Two State", "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "X2", "fullName": "X-Ray Two State", "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "X3", "fullName": "X-Ray Three State", "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "X3", "fullName": "X-Ray Three State", "createdBy": "Admin"},
    {"abbreviation": "X4", "fullName": "X-Ray Four State", "createdBy": "Admin"}
  ]
}
```

Results:

```
{
    "status": 0,
    "success": 14,
    "fail": 11,
    "data": [
        {
            "record_no": 1,
            "abbreviation": "AK",
            "fullName": "Alaska",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 2,
            "abbreviation": "AL",
            "fullName": "Alabama",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 3,
            "abbreviation": "AR",
            "fullName": "Arkansas",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 4,
            "abbreviation": "AS",
            "fullName": "American Samoa ",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 5,
            "abbreviation": "AZ",
            "fullName": "Arizona",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 6,
            "abbreviation": "CA",
            "fullName": "California",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 7,
            "abbreviation": "CO",
            "fullName": "Colorado",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 8,
            "abbreviation": "CT",
            "fullName": "Connecticut",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 9,
            "abbreviation": "DC",
            "fullName": "District of Columbia",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 10,
            "abbreviation": "DE",
            "fullName": "Delaware",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 11,
            "abbreviation": "",
            "fullName": "",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 12,
            "abbreviation": "",
            "fullName": "",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 13,
            "abbreviation": "",
            "fullName": "",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 14,
            "abbreviation": "",
            "fullName": "",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 15,
            "abbreviation": "X1",
            "fullName": "",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 16,
            "abbreviation": "X1",
            "fullName": "",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 17,
            "abbreviation": "X1",
            "fullName": "X-Ray One State",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -3,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 18,
            "abbreviation": "X1",
            "fullName": "X-Ray One State",
            "createdBy": "",
            "status": -2,
            "message": "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and 'createdBy' are required and cannot be empty."
        },
        {
            "record_no": 19,
            "abbreviation": "X1",
            "fullName": "X-Ray One State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 20,
            "abbreviation": "X1",
            "fullName": "X-Ray One State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": -1,
            "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'X1' for key 'abbreviation_UNIQUE'"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 21,
            "abbreviation": "X2",
            "fullName": "X-Ray Two State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 22,
            "abbreviation": "X2",
            "fullName": "X-Ray Two State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": -1,
            "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'X2' for key 'abbreviation_UNIQUE'"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 23,
            "abbreviation": "X3",
            "fullName": "X-Ray Three State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 24,
            "abbreviation": "X3",
            "fullName": "X-Ray Three State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": -1,
            "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'X3' for key 'abbreviation_UNIQUE'"
        },
        {
            "record_no": 25,
            "abbreviation": "X4",
            "fullName": "X-Ray Four State",
            "createdBy": "Admin",
            "status": 1,
            "message": "State created"
        }
    ]
}
```

API Call: `CREATE_MANY.PHP`

```
<?php
/**
 * Public API definition for the ClosingDocs application
 * creating multiple records in the states table
 * PHP version 7.3.9
 *
 * @category API
 * @package  ClosingDocs3
 * @author   Barry S. Rayfield <barry.rayfield@gmail.com>
 * @license  MIT Licence
 * @link     Not Availavle
 */

// Headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ' .
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers,' .
    'Content-Type,' .
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods,' .
    'Authorization,'.
    'X-Requested-With'
);

require_once '../../config/Database.php';
require_once '../../models/State.php';

// Instantiate Database Object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

// Instantiate state object
$state = new State($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$results = array();
$results['status'] = 0;
$results['success'] = 0;
$results['fail'] = 0;
$results['data'] = array();

if (isset($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $items) {
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if (isset($item->abbreviation)
                && isset($item->fullName)
                && isset($item->createdBy)
            ) {
                if ($item->abbreviation != null
                    && $item->fullName != null
                    && $item->createdBy != null
                ) {
                    // Set the properties for the state
                    $state->setAbbreviation($item->abbreviation);
                    $state->setFullName($item->fullName);
                    $state->setCreatedBy($item->createdBy);
                    $state->setLastEdittedBy($item->createdBy);

                    // Create state
                    $stateStatus = $state->create();
                    if ($stateStatus['status'] > 0) {
                        $err = array(
                            'record_no' => $count,
                            'abbreviation' => $item->abbreviation,
                            'fullName' => $item->fullName,
                            'createdBy' => $item->createdBy,
                            'status' => $stateStatus['status'],
                            'message' => $stateStatus['message']
                        );
                        array_push($results['data'], $err);
                        $results['success']++;
                    } else {
                        $err = array(
                            'record_no' => $count,
                            'abbreviation' => $item->abbreviation,
                            'fullName' => $item->fullName,
                            'createdBy' => $item->createdBy,
                            'status' => $stateStatus['status'],
                            'message' => $stateStatus['message']
                        );
                        array_push($results['data'], $err);
                        $results['fail']++;
                    }
                } else {
                    $err = array(
                        'record_no' => $count,
                        'abbreviation' => $item->abbreviation,
                        'fullName' => $item->fullName,
                        'createdBy' => $item->createdBy,
                        'status' => -2,
                        'message' => "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' " .
                            "and 'createdBy' are required and cannot be empty."
                    );
                    array_push($results['data'], $err);
                    $results['fail']++;
                }
            } else {
                $err = array(
                    'record_no' => $count,
                    'abbreviation' =>
                        isset($item->abbreviation) ? $item->abbreviation : '',
                    'fullName' => isset($item->fullName) ? $item->fullName : '',
                    'createdBy' => isset($item->createdBy) ? $item->createdBy : '',
                    'status' => -3,
                    'message' => "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and " .
                        "'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
                );
                array_push($results['data'], $err);
                $results['fail']++;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
} else {
    $results['status'] = -4;
    $results['success'] = 0;
    $results['fail'] = 1;
    $results['message'] = "Malformed request.";
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Class: `STATE.PHP`

```
<?php
/**
 * Public API definition for the ClosingDocs application
 * creating multiple records in the states table
 * PHP version 7.3.9
 *
 * @category API
 * @package  ClosingDocs3
 * @author   Barry S. Rayfield <barry.rayfield@gmail.com>
 * @license  MIT Licence
 * @link     Not Availavle
 */

// Headers
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ' .
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers,' .
    'Content-Type,' .
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods,' .
    'Authorization,'.
    'X-Requested-With'
);

require_once '../../config/Database.php';
require_once '../../models/State.php';

// Instantiate Database Object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->connect();

// Instantiate state object
$state = new State($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$results = array();
$results['status'] = 0;
$results['success'] = 0;
$results['fail'] = 0;
$results['data'] = array();

if (isset($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $items) {
        $count = 1;
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if (isset($item->abbreviation)
                && isset($item->fullName)
                && isset($item->createdBy)
            ) {
                if ($item->abbreviation != null
                    && $item->fullName != null
                    && $item->createdBy != null
                ) {
                    // Set the properties for the state
                    $state->setAbbreviation($item->abbreviation);
                    $state->setFullName($item->fullName);
                    $state->setCreatedBy($item->createdBy);
                    $state->setLastEdittedBy($item->createdBy);

                    // Create state
                    $stateStatus = $state->create();
                    if ($stateStatus['status'] > 0) {
                        $err = array(
                            'record_no' => $count,
                            'abbreviation' => $item->abbreviation,
                            'fullName' => $item->fullName,
                            'createdBy' => $item->createdBy,
                            'status' => $stateStatus['status'],
                            'message' => $stateStatus['message']
                        );
                        array_push($results['data'], $err);
                        $results['success']++;
                    } else {
                        $err = array(
                            'record_no' => $count,
                            'abbreviation' => $item->abbreviation,
                            'fullName' => $item->fullName,
                            'createdBy' => $item->createdBy,
                            'status' => $stateStatus['status'],
                            'message' => $stateStatus['message']
                        );
                        array_push($results['data'], $err);
                        $results['fail']++;
                    }
                } else {
                    $err = array(
                        'record_no' => $count,
                        'abbreviation' => $item->abbreviation,
                        'fullName' => $item->fullName,
                        'createdBy' => $item->createdBy,
                        'status' => -2,
                        'message' => "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' " .
                            "and 'createdBy' are required and cannot be empty."
                    );
                    array_push($results['data'], $err);
                    $results['fail']++;
                }
            } else {
                $err = array(
                    'record_no' => $count,
                    'abbreviation' =>
                        isset($item->abbreviation) ? $item->abbreviation : '',
                    'fullName' => isset($item->fullName) ? $item->fullName : '',
                    'createdBy' => isset($item->createdBy) ? $item->createdBy : '',
                    'status' => -3,
                    'message' => "The parameters 'abbreviation', 'fullName' and " .
                        "'createdBy' are required and can only appear once."
                );
                array_push($results['data'], $err);
                $results['fail']++;
            }
            $count++;
        }
    }
} else {
    $results['status'] = -4;
    $results['success'] = 0;
    $results['fail'] = 1;
    $results['message'] = "Malformed request.";
}
echo json_encode($results);
```

Class: `DATABASE.PHP`

```
<?php
/**
 * Database Connection Configuration definition for the PHP
 * REST API based version of the ClosingDocs application
 * PHP version 7.3.9
 *
 * @category Configuration
 * @package  ClosingDocs3
 * @author   Barry S. Rayfield <barry.rayfield@gmail.com>
 * @license  MIT Licence
 * @link     To be determined
 */
//namespace config;

/**
 * Database Connection class for the ClosingDocs application
 *
 * @category Configuration
 * @package  Myblog
 * @author   Barry S. Rayfield <barry.rayfield@gmail.com>
 * @license  MIT License
 * @link     To be determined
 */
class Database
{
    // DB Params
    private $_host = 'localhost';
    private $_db_name = 'closingdocs3_dev';
    private $_username = 'root';
    private $_password = 'mischeif02';
    private $_conn;

    /**
     * DB Connect
     *
     * @return DB connection
     */
    public function connect()
    {
        $this->_conn = null;

        try {
            $this->_conn = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=' . $this->_host . ';dbname=' . $this->_db_name,
                $this->_username,
                $this->_password
            );
            $this->_conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->_conn;
    }
}
```

Screen Capture from phpMyAdmin:
[image: Screen Capture from phpMyAdmin:]

States table definition from phpMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE `states` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `Abbreviation` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `FullName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `CreatedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastEdittedBy` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastEdittedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='                                                          ';

ALTER TABLE `states`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `abbreviation_UNIQUE` (`Abbreviation`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  ADD KEY `FKSCreatedBy_idx` (`CreatedBy`),
  ADD KEY `FKSLastEdittedBy_idx` (`LastEdittedBy`);

ALTER TABLE `states`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=18;

ALTER TABLE `states`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FKSCreatedBy` FOREIGN KEY (`CreatedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserId`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FKSLastEdittedBy` FOREIGN KEY (`LastEdittedBy`) REFERENCES `users` (`UserId`);
```

One last point is that every time I delete all the records in the States table, in order to rerun the test, I issue the command:

```
ALTER TABLE states AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

in order reset the AUTO_INCREMENT index.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. Let auto-increment do its thing.

Comment: I know I probably shouldn't worry about it but my obsessive compulsive side just won't shut up.

Comment: What's the exact question? Is full incrementation needed for some purposes?

Comment: It concerns me that a failed INSERT (prevented by the database itself) causes the auto_increment index to advance creating a gap in the numbering seq.  I would understand/accept if the gap was caused by a row I deleted but this is a row that never should have made it to the table.  It would be as if I were creating a check register.  Each number has to be accounted for no gaps, no deletes.  If a check is destroyed or not used it is voided and not deleted.  I had thought an auto_incremented column could be used for the check number but that can't be unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: To answer you question Tajniak, in this specific situation full incrementation is not needed but in a future situation it might be and I would like to know if an auto_incremented column is something that can be relied on for the task.